# SVN Backout but keep changes locally

Tags: svn, undo, revert, backout

With SVN command line, whats the best way to back out committed changes but to retain them on your local revision? i.e. I want the final state of the remote repository to be what it was before the last commit, and I want the final state of my local revision to have the changes that were backed out (so that I can spend some time fixing and then recommit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reverse merge unwanted changeset(s) in Working Copy
2. Commit revision
3. Update WC to HEAD-1 revision (HEAD before your changes).